# l^-1∈L(w;v) is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

If l∈L(v;w) is bijective, then l^-1∈L(w;v) too?
I'm not sure if it's this way that's why I ask, I'd appreciate your help.Until now I have done this...
”=⇒” Suppose T is invertible.
To show that T is injective, suppose that u, v ∈ V are such that T (u) = T (v). Apply the inverse $$T^−1$$ of T to obtain $$ T^−1 T u = T^−1$$ T v so that u = v. Hence T is injective.
To show that T is surjective, we need to show that for every w ∈ W there is a v ∈ V
such that T v = w. Take $$v = T^−1w ∈ V$$ . Then $$T(T^−1w) = w$$. Hence T is surjective.
”⇐=” Suppose that T is injective and surjective. We need to show that T is invertible. We
define a map S ∈ L(W, V ) as follows. Since T is surjective, we know that for every w ∈ W
there exists a v ∈ V such that T v = w. Moreover, since T is injective, this v is uniquely
determined. Hence define Sw = v.
We claim that S is the inverse of T. Note that for all w ∈ W we have T Sw = T v = w
so that T S = IW . Similarly for all v ∈ V we have ST v = Sw = v so that ST = IV .
It remains to show that S is a linear map. For all w1, w2 ∈ W we have
T(Sw1 + Sw2) = T Sw1 + T Sw2 = w1 + w2,
so that Sw1 + Sw2 is the unique vector v in V such that T v = w1 + w2 = w. Hence
Sw1 + Sw2 = v = Sw = S(w1 + w2).

Comment: Any function is invertible if and only if it is bijective.  So you only need to show that the inverse is linear.  You should also show the inverse commutes with scalars to complete the proof.

Comment: How would be the displacement with scalars?, I still have a little doubt about that topic. @JonathanBrown

Comment: I don't know what you mean by displacement.  For a function T to be linear, it must satisfy $T(c v) = c T(v)$ for all input vectors $v$ and scalars $c$, and it must satisfy that $T(v+w) = T(v)+T(w)$ for all input vectors $v,w$.